# Mutual independence in a coin toss situation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

A question states that a fair coin is tossed thrice, and these events are defined; $A$: the first toss is a head; $B$: the second toss is a head; $C$: exactly two consecutive heads or exactly two consecutive tails occur.

That all three are pairwise independent is obvious. However, apparently they're also mutually independent.

How does that work? As I understand it, if the knowledge of two events here affects the chances of another, the events wouldn't be mutually independent. Here, if you know the first and second tosses to both yield heads, the probability of C would be 1.

So how are they mutually independent?

Comment: "However, apparently they're also mutually independent." +1 to your analysis, which I agree with.  You have just proven that the probability of event C occurring is affected by whether A and B both occur.  I am unclear whether the phrase "*mutually independent* signifies something else.  However, there are 4 possibilities re either event A occurs or it doesn't, and either event B occurs or it doesn't.  No way is the chance of event C occurring *unaffected* by which of the 4 cases (re events A and B) pertain.

Comment: They're not mutually independent - this is a canonical example of a set of events that are pairwise independent but not mutually independent.

Comment: @user2661923: mutual independence here, I think, is the strong notion mentioned (here)[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)]. Karl: yeah, I've heard of cases similar to this. So the in-book answer's just wrong?

Comment: They are mutually independent in the sense that $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know $A$ and $B$ occur, then you still don't know whether $C$ occurs, because the third toss could be heads or tails.  The probability isn't $1$ because it says exactly two consecutive.  No matter how $A$ and $B$ turn up, there will always be one way to achieve exactly two consecutive.

It appears $P(A \cap B \cap C) = 1/8 = P(A)P(B)P(C) = 1/2\cdot 1/2 \cdot 1/2.$. Together with the pairwise independence, the three events are mutually independent.

Comment: Oh, yeah, like the sample space for the two-coin toss involves 8 possible compund events, of which 4 are favourable to C, so P(C)=$\frac{1}{2}$. When two heads come up, the sample space gets reduced to ${(H,H,T),(H,H,H)}$, of which only the former is favourable to C, so the probability is still two. Is that right?

Comment: So perhaps sometimes using the formulas might be better than trying to use intuition, because you never know what you might miss, right?

Comment: Use the formulas to train/improve your intuition, Harry.

Comment: @HarryHolmes To be clear: $P(C|(A \cap B))=\frac{P(HHT)}{P(HHH,HHT)}=\frac{1/8}{2//8}.$